# Updating a PSQL Table

Tags: php, psql

I am wanting to update a psql table called user_setup, off a html page.
I have done this 2 parts. First there is a drop list which has all the user names.
Once a username is selected and submit is pressed the ID, User First name, User Last name, Breaks1 name, Breaks1 Start & Breaks1 finish for that user is displayed in there text boxes.  (This works)
What i want now is to able to edit the Breaks1 name, breaks1 start and breaks1 finish data and update the users_setup table.I have created a button 'Update details' to do this.
When pressed though i am geeting the following errors on the page :

```
Notice: Undefined variable: POST in /Users/davidjones/Sites/VCB V2/edit.php on line 71

Notice: Undefined variable: POST in /Users/davidjones/Sites/VCB V2/edit.php on line 71

Notice: Undefined variable: POST in /Users/davidjones/Sites/VCB V2/edit.php on line 71

Notice: Undefined variable: POST in /Users/davidjones/Sites/VCB V2/edit.php on line 72

Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "," LINE 1: ...sers_setup SET breaks1_name = '', breaks1_start = , breaks1_... ^ in /Users/davidjones/Sites/VCB V2/edit.php on line 72
Update failed!!
```

I presume i have got the $POST names wrong but i have tried changing them but still get the errors.

The code i have written is as follows :

```
    <section>
       <h2>Enter username</h2>
          <ul>
             <form name="display-username" action="edit.php" method="POST" >
               <select name="username">
                  <?php
                   $conn = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=vcbv3 user=postgres");
                   // get all the uid from the uid column in users
                   $result = pg_query($conn, "SELECT user_uid FROM users_setup");
                   if (!$result) 
                    {
                     // error message  
                     echo "An error occurred.\n";
                     exit;
                    }
                     // display on screen all uid data from users_setup in the dropdown
                     while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) 
                    {
                    echo "<option value='$row[0]'> $row[0] </option>\n";
                    }
                  ?>   
                  <!-- submit button to select username-->              
                   <li><input type="submit" name="submit" /></li>
              </select>
            </form>
          </ul>
     </body>
    </section>

     <!-- submit button to select username-->             
 <?php
        // find the username details on the users_setup table
        $db = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=vcbv3 user=postgres");
        $result1 = pg_query($db, "SELECT * from users_setup WHERE user_uid= '$_POST[username]'");
        $row = pg_fetch_assoc($result1);
        if (isset($_POST['submit']))
          {
           // display the username details 
           echo "<ul>
                     <form name='update' action='edit.php' method='POST' >
                      <li>id:</li><li><input type='text' name='id_updated' value='$row[id]' /></li>
                      <li>First Name:</li><li><input type='text' name='user_first_name_updated' value='$row[user_first_name]' /></li>
                      <li>Last Name:</li><li><input type='text' name='user_last_name_updated' value='$row[user_last_name]' /></li>
                      <li>Breaks 1 Name:</li><li><input type='text' name='breaks1_name_updated' value='$row[breaks1_name]' /></li>
                      <li>Breaks 1 Start:</li><li><input type='time' name='breaks1_start_updated' value='$row[breaks1_start]' /></li>
                      <li>Breaks 1 Finish:</li><li><input type='time' name='breaks1_finish_updated' value='$row[breaks1_finish]' /></li>
                </ul>";
          }
    ?>
                   <li><input type="submit" name="Update"  value="Update details"/></li>

     <?php
     if (isset($_POST['Update']))
          {
            // Update details on the users_setup table
            $db = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=vcbv3 user=postgres");
            $result = pg_query($db, "UPDATE users_setup SET breaks1_name = '$POST[breaks1_name_updated]', breaks1_start = $POST[breaks1_start_updated], breaks1_finish = $POST[breaks1_finish_updated]
              WHERE id = $POST[id_updated]");
           if (!$result){
                           echo "Update failed!!";
                         }
                      else
                         {
                           echo "Update successfull;";
                         } 


          }
    ?>
```

Can anyone help me and show me what i have done wrong please?

Comment: you are doing wrong almost everything. Mixing up HTML with PHP, uses of GLOBALS variable directly, uses of pg_query/pg_connect which is deprecated.

Comment: Hello Kallosz  I am still learning PHP do you where i could find how to do what i need or help me rewrite this?

Comment: `$POST` != `$_POST`

Comment: instead of using pg_** use PDO http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: instead of $_POST (GLOBALS) you can use https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html

Comment: Thank you kallosz

Comment: you can also try using template engine instead of mixing HTML with PHP. https://twig.symfony.com/

Comment: Just a note, the pg_ functions aren't deprecated and are fine to use. The [pg_connect()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-connect.php) deprecation notice only applies to the multiple-parameters form which OP isn't using. You shouldn't use pg_query though, use pg_prepare/pg_execute. PDO is also good, especially if you might want to use another database type someday.